# Puyo Puyo Tetris not tracking stats

Tags: nintendo-switch, puyo-puyo-tetris

After playing an Endless Match in Puyo Puyo Tetris for Nintendo Switch and going to the stats screen it says I haven't played any Endless game. Same for all modes, none of my gameplay stats are recorded.

The console itself is connected to the internet.

I noticed that after finishing a match it shows Updating Stats but it never shows a confirmation message that the stats where updated.

Do I need to activate something to get the stats recorded?